How can I create a Lua filter that changes italic & bold markdown to Emphasis & Strong Emphasis styles with pandoc for LibreOffice Writer ODT file?
I have input.md:
---
title: My example document
---

## Overview

*I am italic*

**I am bold**

If I run:
pandoc input.md -o output.odt

I get an odt file with the expected formatting. However, in order to prepare the document for conversion to a PDF/UA-compliant PDF, I have to manually remove the bold and italic formatting and style those text items as "Strong Emphasis" and "Emphasis", respectively, from the Styles menu.
I want to automate this, so I created custom_styles.lua:
function Strong(elem)
    return pandoc.Span(elem.content, {class = "StrongEmphasis"})
end

function Emph(elem)
    return pandoc.Span(elem.content, {class = "Emphasis"})
end

If I run:
pandoc --lua-filter=custom_styles.lua -o output.odt input.md

My odt document now shows "No Character Style" for the text that was bold and italic.
Can somebody explain what I should be doing to achieve this?
Thanks I

LibreOffice Writer has an Export as PDF option that allows you to specify PDF/UA compliance. It raises direct formatting issues when text is bold / italic but passes if text is styled Strong Emphasis / Emphasis. The created PDF then passes PAC 2024 validations for PDF/UA, WCAG & Quality. That's all  I'm trying to achieve right now.

Can you try with {['custom-style'] = "StrongEmphasis"} instead of class?

Unfortunately, it's the same. I end up with plain text.

So, I've just updated pandoc to the very latest version, and although it still doesn't work for odt, it is working for docx. Hoping, I can find a workaround from docx to odt...

This should work, but the custom styles must already exist in the reference odt.
To create the reference ODT, first run
pandoc --output=my-refdoc.odt --print-default-data-file=reference.odt

Edit the resulting file my-refdoc.odt, add the custom styles, and then pass the modified file to pandoc via --reference-doc=my-refdoc.odt when doint the conversion.
The filter should set the custom-style attribute, so the code should use {['custom-style'] = "StrongEmphasis"}.
Everything should work once those things are in place.

I had to change it to {['custom-style'] = "Strong Emphasis"} but working!
